# Must an epsilon neighbourhood be small?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there any requirement or restriction that an epsilon neighbourhood $V_{\epsilon}(a)$ be small? Could I use $\epsilon = 1$ if my needs demand it?

Comment: There is no restriction on epsilon neighbourhood's size in general.

Comment: Yes, sure. And by the way who can say what is the smallest $\epsilon$?

Comment: the unique restriction for the choice of $\epsilon$ is that it must be some positive number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $\epsilon > 0$, it can be whatever you need it to be. It doesn't mean that your proof of a given theorem will work when $\epsilon = 1$. I can't guarantee that, of course. But there really is nothing criminal about choosing $\epsilon = 1$.

It's really the same logic as with functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. You can choose whatever $\epsilon > 0$ that you desire. When doing proofs, you do tend to keep it arbitrary but fixed though.